# How can I get a specific parameter from location.search?

Tags: javascript, url

If I had a URL such as

```
http://localhost/search.php?year=2008
```

How would I write a JavaScript function to grab the variable *year* and see if it contains anything?

I know it can be done with `location.search` but I can’t figure out how it grabs parameters.

Comment: `string yr = location.search.substring(6);`  `alert(yr);`

Comment: location.search.split("year=")[1] only in simplest

Comment: Looks like the question is closed but the most current answer isn't here:
new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('year')

Comment: You can use URLSearchParams.getAll() to return all of the values associated with a particular parameter:

console.log(urlParams.getAll('size'));

Answer (score 77):

You may use [`window.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class:

```
new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('year')
// Returns 2008 for href = "http://localhost/search.php?year=2008".
// Or in two steps:
const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
const year = params.get('year');
```

Comment: window.URL is a handy one, if only using latest Chrome and Firefox

Comment: this shuld be the accepted answer nowadays

Comment: @pungggi ...until your client uses internet explorer :(

Comment: @haykam Then use a polyfill for that!

Answer (score 60):

My favorite way for getting URL params is this approach:

```
var parseQueryString = function() {

    var str = window.location.search;
    var objURL = {};

    str.replace(
        new RegExp( "([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g" ),
        function( $0, $1, $2, $3 ){
            objURL[ $1 ] = $3;
        }
    );
    return objURL;
};

//Example how to use it: 
var params = parseQueryString();
alert(params["foo"]);
```

Comment: That old man always says "when you have a problem that can only be resolved with regular expressions, you actually have two problems".

Comment: I love this, very cute! is there a reason you capture the '='? you could say /([^?=&]+)=([^&]*)/g and have your params be (match, key, value)?

Comment: isn't location.search.split("year=")[1] much simpler?

Comment: @Rodrigo if you have more than one params it will blow

Comment: A more elegant —no regex / more modern (2018) — solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42316411/328117

Answer (score 52):

A non-regex approach, you can simply split by the character '&' and iterate through the key/value pair:

```
function getParameter(paramName) {
  var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
      i, val, params = searchString.split("&");

  for (i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
    val = params[i].split("=");
    if (val[0] == paramName) {
      return val[1];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

### 2020 EDIT:

Nowadays, in [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams) you can use the [`URLSearchParams` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams):

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams('?year=2020&month=02&day=01')

// You can access specific parameters:
console.log(params.get('year'))
console.log(params.get('month'))

// And you can iterate over all parameters
for (const [key, value] of params) {
  console.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `val` a global in there?

Comment: then can i do

if(getParameter("year") != "") { var year=getParameter("year"); document.location.href=page.php?year=$year&etc etc.

Comment: @sarmenhb: You can do:  var year=getParameter("year"); if (year){ document.location.href='page.php?year='+year;}

Comment: @Luca Matteis: No, val is not a global in there. 
It's defined as a local var in var searchString, i, val, ...

Comment: Elegant and easy to use! Why isn't this marked as the answer?

Answer (score 16):

This question is old and things have evolved in JavaScript.
You can now do this:

```
const params = {}
document.location.search.substr(1).split('&').forEach(pair => {
  [key, value] = pair.split('=')
  params[key] = value
})
```

and you get `params.year` that contains `2008`.
You would also get other query params in your `params` object.

---

**Edit**: a shorter/cleaner way to do this:

```
const params = new Map(location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(kv => kv.split('=')))
```

You can then test if the `year` param exists with:

```
params.has('year')  // true
```

Or retrieve it with:

```
params.get('year')  // 2008
```

---

#### Edit 2020

You can convert URL params to an Object:

```js
const params = location.search.slice(1).split('&').reduce((acc, s) => {
  const [k, v] = s.split('=')
  return Object.assign(acc, {[k]: v})
}, {})
```

Then it can be used as a regular JS Object:

```js
params.year  // 2008
```

Comment: You should use a .reduce() instead of .forEach

Comment: Doesn't work with .reduce(). Only first param is written to params object. Checked in Chrome dev tools. Can you please double check and and replace with forEach() instead?

Comment: @vinyll @tylik ```const getQueryObject = locationSearchString =>
  locationSearchString
    .substr(1)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((queryObject, keyValuePair) => {
      const [key, value] = keyValuePair.split('=');

      queryObject[key] = value;
      return queryObject;
    }, {});```

Comment: you should use URL but if you're going to do it this way you need to call `decodeURIComponent` on every key and value after splitting by & and =. This is how it's possible to encode = and & in the keys and values themselves as well as other things like # as they'll all be encoded.

Answer (score 8):

The following uses regular expressions and searches only on the query string portion of the URL.

Most importantly, this method supports normal and array parameters as in 
`http://localhost/?fiz=zip&foo[]=!!=&bar=7890#hashhashhash`

```
function getQueryParam(param) {
    var result =  window.location.search.match(
        new RegExp("(\\?|&)" + param + "(\\[\\])?=([^&]*)")
    );

    return result ? result[3] : false;
}

console.log(getQueryParam("fiz"));
console.log(getQueryParam("foo"));
console.log(getQueryParam("bar"));
console.log(getQueryParam("zxcv"));
```

**Output:**

```
zip
!!=
7890
false
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function gup( name ) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
var year = gup("year"); // returns "2008"
```

Comment: You should use `window.location.search` instead of `window.location.href`.  This would simplify your expressions not having to check for the hash or query markers

Comment: It would be a good idea to **escape all regex meta characters** in "name" before creating a regex off of it.

Answer (score 6):

It took me a while to find the answer to this question.  Most people seem to be suggesting regex solutions.  I strongly prefer to use code that is tried and tested as opposed to regex that I or someone else thought up on the fly.

I use the parseUri library available here:
http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/

It allows you to do exactly what you are asking for:

```
var uri = 'http://localhost/search.php?year=2008';
var year = uri.queryKey['year'];
// year = '2008'
```

Comment: var year = parseUri(window.location.search).queryKey['year']; 
Is a more relevant example. The one above does not work with version 1.2 of the parseUri script.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to have

```
if (document.location.search.indexOf('yourtext=') >= 0) {
    // your code
} else {
    // what happens?
}
```

### indexOf()

The `indexOf(text)` function returns

- **A WHOLE NUMBER BELOW 0** when the text passed in the function is not in whatever variable or string you are looking for - in this case `document.location.search`.
- **A WHOLE NUMBER EQUAL TO 0 OR HIGHER** when the text passed in the function is in whatever variable or string you are looking for - in this case `document.location.search`.

---

I hope this was useful, *[@gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo)*

Comment: This fails with a query string like `?notyourtext=foo`

Comment: ...and fails when using `?yourtext=foo&notyourtext=bar`.

Answer (score 4):

A Simple One-Line Solution:

```js
let query = Object.assign.apply(null, location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(entry => ({ [entry.split('=')[0]]: entry.split('=')[1] })));
```

Expanded & Explained:

```js
// define variable
let query;

// fetch source query
query = location.search;

// skip past the '?' delimiter
query = query.slice(1);

// split source query by entry delimiter
query = query.split('&');

// replace each query entry with an object containing the query entry
query = query.map((entry) => {

   // get query entry key
   let key = entry.split('=')[0];

   // get query entry value
   let value = entry.split('=')[1];

   // define query object
   let container = {};

   // add query entry to object
   container[key] = value;

   // return query object
   return container;
});

// merge all query objects
query = Object.assign.apply(null, query);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a variant of Alex's - but needed to to convert the param appearing multiple times to an array. There seem to be many options.  I didn't want rely on another library for something this simple.  I suppose one of the other options posted here may be better -  I adapted Alex's because  of the straight forwardness.

```
parseQueryString = function() {
    var str = window.location.search;
    var objURL = {};

    // local isArray - defer to underscore, as we are already using the lib
    var isArray = _.isArray

    str.replace(
        new RegExp( "([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g" ),
        function( $0, $1, $2, $3 ){

            if(objURL[ $1 ] && !isArray(objURL[ $1 ])){
                // if there parameter occurs more than once, convert to an array on 2nd
                var first = objURL[ $1 ]
                objURL[ $1 ] = [first, $3]
            } else if(objURL[ $1 ] && isArray(objURL[ $1 ])){
                // if there parameter occurs more than once, add to array after 2nd
                objURL[ $1 ].push($3)
            }
            else
            {
                // this is the first instance
                objURL[ $1 ] = $3;
            }

        }
    );
    return objURL;
};
```

Comment: If a param appears more than once, it should only be treated as an array if it ends with `[]` (e.g. `foo[]=1&foo[]=2`).  Otherwise, you should use either the first or last occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit with this problem and at this end I used this:

```
function getJsonFromUrl() {
  return Object.assign(...location.search.substr(1).split("&").map(sliceProperty));
}
```

- `Object.assign` to transform a list of object into one object
- Spread operator `...` to transform an array into a list
- `location.search.substr(1).split("&")` to get all parameters as array of properties (`foo=bar`)
- `map` walk each properties and split them into an array (either call `splitProperty` or `sliceProperty`).

`splitProperty`:

```
  function splitProperty(pair) {
    [key, value] = pair.split("=")
    return { [key]: decodeURIComponent(value) }
  }
```

- Split by `=`
- Deconstruct the array into an array of two elements
- Return a new object with the dynamic property syntax

`sliceProperty`:

```
  function sliceProperty(pair) {
    const position = pair.indexOf("="),
      key = pair.slice(0, position),
      value = pair.slice(position + 1, pair.length);
    return { [key]: decodeURIComponent(value) }
  }
```

- Set the position of `=`, key and value
- Return a new object with the dynamic property syntax

I think `splitProperty` is prettier but `sliceProperty` is faster. Run [JsPerf](https://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substr-vs-substring-vs-split-vs-regexp/2) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the params from location.search with one line:

```
const params = new Map(this.props.location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(param => param.split('=')))
```

Then, simply:

```
if(params.get("year")){
  //year exists. do something...
} else {
  //year doesn't exist. do something else...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 answer:

```
const parseQueryString = (path = window.location.search) =>
  path.slice(1).split('&').reduce((car, cur) => {
   const [key, value] = cur.split('=')
   return { ...car, [key]: value } 
  }, {})
```

for example:

```
parseQueryString('?foo=bar&foobar=baz')
// => {foo: "bar", foobar: "baz"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I like to do:

```
window.location.search
    .substr(1)
    .split('&')
    .reduce(
        function(accumulator, currentValue) {
            var pair = currentValue
                .split('=')
                .map(function(value) {
                    return decodeURIComponent(value);
                });

            accumulator[pair[0]] = pair[1];

            return accumulator;
        },
        {}
    );
```

Of course you can make it more compact using modern syntax or writing everything into one line...

I leave that up to you.