# How to pass url parameters onto a iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have the following webpage

```
www.fake.com/sample.html
```

I could pass some parameters to that webpage, like so

```
www.fake.com/sample.html?count=10&format=gold
```

this page has an iframe in it, I would like to pass any parameters that the main page gets to the enclosed iframe. If the main page is called like so

```
www.fake.com/sample.html?count=10&format=gold
```

the iframe in the sample page should be called with those same paramters.

```
<iframe src="www.fake.com/framed_page.html?count=10&format=gold"></iframe>
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: FYI, your slashes are the wrong way round

Comment: Fixed the slashes. Also, i don't have access to a server-side language

Answer (score 5):

In the javascript of the child document (`framed_page.html`) you can call `window.parent.location` to get the location object of `sample.html`. Call `window.parent.location.search` to get the query string

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523266/how-can-i-get-a-specific-parameter-from-location-search`  My favorite is the @JustinJohnson answer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most reliable way (because it doesn't require JavaScript to work) would be to use a server-side language to compose the correct iframe URL from the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

In PHP:

```
<iframe src=
    "www.fake.com\framed_page.html?<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; ?>">
</iframe>
```

Comment: That's what I was going to go with, but there's no mention of php in the OP.

Comment: Then again, the question does ask for the query string in the iframe src attribute rather than in the iframe dom.

Comment: @adam yeah, it would need to be put into the `load` event to work with JS - perfectly fine but won't work with JS disabled obviously, which is the only downside. It will depend on what the OP can use.