# Is it possible to have setTimeout not restart when going to different pages on the site?

Tags: javascript, cookies

If I have setTimeout in a script in the header of my site is it possible to have it continue to run as a user goes from page to page without restarting. Is this something I could use cookies to do? Are there any examples I could look at?

Comment: No.  The timers are all killed when the page is rebuilt, so your script will have to restart on each page reload.  If you want to keep a context across multiple sections of content, you have to build a "single-page application".

Comment: Do you mean setInterval? setTimeout only fires once, where setInterval repeats.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options with this.

- Add a GET query to the URL string. This looks like www.ex.com/index.html?time=300024

You would capture the click of all anchor tags, and if it points to your own site, it appends ?time=${time} to the url. Then, on the next page, when initializing the timer, separate out the time in location.search on the next page. Note that this method won't keep the exact time because there will be a delay while the page and DOM are loaded.

[Get Parameter from javascript's location.search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523266/how-can-i-get-a-specific-parameter-from-location-search)

- load the content of the website through ajax

This way, you would completely reengineer your site so that any link to internal parts to your site would actually use AJAX to query new content. This means you would never change pages per se, and the javascript timeout would never be unloaded. This isn't the most recommended practice. Here's a basic example:

[A simple AJAX website with jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to time the user and store it in a cookie and then add to the cookie when they go to a different page?

Comment: I think it would serve the same function as the first option, except more users might have cookies disabled. Access from a query string might also be faster than accessing a cookie, though I'm not sure. If it's time-sensitive, you would want to look into which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage to save the state.

Setup your regular setTimeout. When it initiates, have it load whatever state data it needs from localStorage. Whenever it updates the data, it should save it back to localStorage for persistence.

If you need specific details on how to do this, leave a comment with your questions and I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session cookie to save the time you want your setTimeout code to execute.

On each page:

- Check if the cookie has a value.  If not, set it to something like `Date.now() + delayValue`, where delayValue is how long to wait in milliseconds.
- Check `cookieValue - Date.now()` -- if > 0, use it as your setTimeout timer value. if <= 0, your timer function should have already run