# jQuery Validation dynamic change language error messages when changing `mylocale`

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my home page I can change language: `href="home?mylocale=en"` or `href="home?mylocale=ru"`. I use jQuery validate with email and password input. When I add `<script src="resources/assets/js/messages_ru.min.js"></script>` all messages are translated to the Russian, but I want to translate default language error messages only when I choose `href="home?mylocale=ru"`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining two other SO answers can do what you want:

1. Parse and analyse `window.location` to see if `mylocale` is set to `ru` (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523293/3727050) answer)
2. Load the script dynamically (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719185/3727050) one)

The result will be (in a `<script>` tag):

```
function getParameter(paramName) {

    var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
        i, val, params = searchString.split("&");

    for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
        val = params[i].split("=");
        if (val[0] == paramName) {
            return val[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}


if (getParameter("mylocale") == "ru") 
    $.getScript("resources/assets/js/messages_ru.min.js");
```

A slightly modified version can be used to load any language:

```
var loc = getParameter("mylocale");
if (loc != null) 
    $.getScript("resources/assets/js/messages_"+loc+".min.js");
```

Comment: I added your answer in a <script> tag and put in a <head> tag, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Will need to be after jQuery is loaded. You can also try to put the script tag at the bottom of the page (just before closing body). If still does not work, can you inspect element and see if there are any errors in the console? `$.getScript()` might require full `http://...` URL

Comment: `getParameter` is not defined

Comment: Not sure?? We just defined the function!